# Bootstrap navbar col are stacking horizontally instead of vertically in desktop but stacking vertically in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, nav

`I'm just using a basic bootstrap theme` 
`https://startbootstrap.com/previews/creative`

[`bootstrap link items mobile expanded`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEEMK.png)
[`bootstrap link items mobile`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BnOQ.png)
[`desktop basic icons`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODKPc.png)
[`desktop contact link items container dimensions`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8f6b.png)
[`mobile basic icons`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVRl0.png)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-3" id="mainnav">
<div class="container px-12 px-lg-12">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">start bootstrap</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarresponsive" aria-controls="navbarresponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarresponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#services">services</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container px-12 px-lg-12 text-center col-lg-12">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="width:450px">
<i class="bi bi-telephone"></i>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="width:450px">
<i class="bi bi-telephone"></i>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="width:450px">
<i class="bi bi-telephone"></i>
</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Here's my code, I think it was right to place the new containers within the navigation class itself with the container-fluid to keep the items within the actual window instead of being pushed off canvas

I want to add a 2nd row of items in the navigation bar and assumed if I set the width to 12 it would auto indent and have them stack vertically in both desktop and mobile.

However while it does for mobile quite neatly, for "desktop" it splits the window in half as though it were 6 and 6 width with a full span.

Comment: The `navbar-expand-lg` class likely has a flex behaviour, forcing its children, in your case the two `.container`, to stay horizontally on a single row resulting in the 6 and 6 observation. Add flex wrap class on the navbar to fix this: `navbar navbar-expand-lg flex-lg-wrap …`